# missing windows keyboard buttons on rMBP

Tags: keyboard, windows, mapping

I need the Home, delete, insert and all the other buttons found in a typical windows keyboard. I don't know how to access them on my MacBook pro. The only one I know is fn-delete for delete. Is there a comprehensive list anywhere? I've searched thru the questions here but non really answer my question. There's similar ones including how to use windows type keys on OS X. But my question is Windows, and only windows related.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you give us some more context on your problem? Do you want to use the keys in OS X, in Windows running in Parallels/VMWare, in Windows running via Bootcamp? Also it might help to add a link to the question which didn't help you so people don't propose the same solutions again.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a support page on this: [Boot Camp: MacBook Pro built-in keyboard mapping in Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1220).

Comment: I run windows exclusively. running via Bootcamp.

Comment: Yes, nonetheless, these will still work in Windows as the title of the support page suggests: *Boot Camp*: MacBook Pro built-in keyboard mapping in *Windows*.